# How to implement Xml Serialization with inherited classes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, serialization

I have two classes : base class name Component and inheritd class named DBComponent

```
[Serializable]
public class Component
{
    private string name = string.Empty;
    private string description = string.Empty;  
}

[Serializable]
public class DBComponent : Component
{
    private List<string> spFiles = new List<string>();

    // Storage Procedure Files
    [XmlArrayItem("SPFile", typeof(string))]
    [XmlArray("SPFiles")]
    public List<string> SPFiles
    {
        get { return spFiles; }
        set { spFiles = value; }
    }

    public DBComponent(string name, string description)
        : base(name, description)
    { }
}  

[Serializable]
public class ComponentsCollection
{
  private static ComponentsCollection instance = null;
  private List<Component> components = new List<Component>();

  public List<Component> Components
  {
      get { return components; }
      set 
      { 
            components = value; 
      }
  }

   public static ComponentsCollection GetInstance()
    {
        if (ccuInstance == null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    PopulateComponents();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static void PopulateComponents()
    {
        instance = new CCUniverse();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType());
        instance = xs.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create("Components.xml")) as ComponentsCollection;
    }
}
```

}

I want read\write from a Xml file. I know that I need to implement the Serialization for DBComponent class otherwise it will not read it.But i cannot find any simple article for that. all the articles that I found were too complex for this simple scenario.
The Xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ComponentsCollection>    
    <Components>
            <DBComponent Name="Tenant Historical Database" Description="Tenant Historical Database">
                    <SPFiles>
                        <SPFile>Setup\TenantHistoricalSP.sql</SPFile>
                    </SPFiles>
            </DBComponent>
            <Component Name="Agent" Description="Desktop Agent" />
        </Components>  
  </ComponentsCollection>
```

Can someone please give me a simple example of how to read this kind of xml file and what should be implemented ?

Thanks
Lior

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to tell the `XmlSerializer` the classes you intend to serialize or deserialize using the `XmlArrayItem()` attribute. Each different type also needs its own element name. For example:

```
public class ComponentDerviedClass1: Component
public class ComponentDerivedClass2: Component
public class ComponentDerivedClass3: Component

// ...

public class ComponentsCollection
{
    [XmlArray("Components")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ComponentDerivedClass1", typeof(ComponentDerivedClass1))]
    [XmlArrayItem("ComponentDerivedClass2", typeof(ComponentDerivedClass2))]
    [XmlArrayItem("ComponentDerivedClass3", typeof(ComponentDerivedClass3))]
    public List<Component> Components
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This would read an XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ComponentsCollection>    
  <Components>
     <ComponentDerivedClass1>
         <!-- ... -->
     </ComponentDerivedClass1>
     <ComponentDerivedClass2>
         <!-- ... -->
     </ComponentDerivedClass2>
     <ComponentDerivedClass3>
         <!-- ... -->
     </ComponentDerivedClass3>
   </Components>  
</ComponentsCollection>
```

Multiple instances of each element can be present (or none).

Answer (score 15):

Two options for different scenrios: tell the base-class

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(DBComponent))]
public class Component
{
    private string name = string.Empty;
    private string description = string.Empty;  
}
```

Or: tell the collection:

```
[XmlArray]
[XmlArrayItem("Component", typeof(Component))]
[XmlArrayItem("DBComponent", typeof(DBComponent))]
public List<Component> Components {...}
```

Actually, you can also use [XmlElement(...)] in place of [XmlArrayItem] if you don't want the outer node (Components). Also: you don't need [Serializable].

Comment: Note for myself: What (I think) Marc Gravell is saying is that you can leave out the "Components" node from the XML if you remove [XmlArray] and change each of the [XmlArrayItem] attributes to [XmlElement] on the Components list

Comment: Thanks for this answer that details how to dodge the use of an external list node!