# C# XML Serializing with Abstract Class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I'm currently trying to set up some commands as classes for serializing for a communication protocol.  My code is basically as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("Message")]
[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    private Command[] _commands;

    [XmlAttribute("ver")]
    public int Version { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("msid")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Commands")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(HealthCheckCommand))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(TestCommand))]
    public Command[] Commands
    {
        get { return _commands; }
        set { _commands = value; }
    }
}

public enum CommandTypes
{
    healthcheck
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "Command")]
public abstract class Command
{
    String CommandType { get; set; }
}

public class HealthCheckCommand : Command
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string CommandType
    {
        get { return "healthcheck"; }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}

public class TestCommand : Command
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string CommandType
    {
        get { return "test"; }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

What I need to get from this is:

```
<Message ver="1" msid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
  <Commands>
    <Command type="healthcheck" />
    <Command type="test" />
  </Commands>
</Message>
```

What I'm getting is:

```
<Message ver="1" msid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
  <Commands>
    <HealthCheckCommand type="healthcheck" />
    <TestCommand type="test" />
  </Commands>
</CTM>
```

When I try to override the XmlArrayItem name with the same name, it of course throws an error.  If I use a list, then it works, but I get all the namespace stuff inside of the subtypes, which I don't want.  I could go in and remove those namespace items after the fact, but I'd rather not.  There must be a way to do this.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

Here's the serialization code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Message));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.txt"))
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("", "");
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

            using (
            XmlWriter xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlwriter, message, xmlSerializerNamespaces);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inherit XMLType of base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128732/inherit-xmltype-of-base-class)

Answer (score 3):

Include the derived types by adding the relevant `XmlInclude` attributes onto `Message`:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(HealthCheckCommand))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(TestCommand))]
```

Then specify the element name for your `Command[]` array items:

```
[XmlArrayItem("Command")]
```

This creates XML like this, which is probably the same as when you used a `List`:

```
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ver="0" msid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
    <Commands>
        <Command xsi:type="HealthCheckCommand" type="healthcheck" />
        <Command xsi:type="TestCommand" type="test" />
    </Commands>
</Message>
```

Unfortunately the `xsi:type` attributes are required in order for deserialisation to work (else how would the serialiser know which types to use?).  These can easily be removed after the fact, though.  Parse the XML with `XDocument` and remove them like so:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

doc.Descendants()
   .Attributes(xsi + "type")
   .Remove();

doc.Descendants()
   .Attributes()
   .Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration && a.Value == xsi)
   .Remove();
```

Comment: My sub-commands have
p3:type="testcommand" rather than xsi:type and they have their own xmlns...how do I remove the sub xmlns?

Comment: You'll have the add the code you're using to serialize, as that's not the result I get.  At a guess you're passing a `XmlSerializerNamespaces` to the serializer?

Comment: I've added my serialization code.  Could you add yours?  Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely my serializer.  If I use the 
            XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("", ""); 
it will do the weird stuff with adding namespace to subtypes and the p3 stuff

Comment: You'll get semantically the same result. Either way, you need to write to / parse into an `XDocument` and remove the attributes using the code in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, the removing of the attributes works well, but I'm not sure I can do that, as these will be sent as commands - need to serialize/deserialize, and when I remove the namespace, the deserializing no longer works.