# Generic method check parameter in runtime

Tags: c#, generics

```
public override void Test<T> T input)
{
  if(input is TypeA)
   {
    var expected =input as TypeA;
     foreach(var a in expected.Values)
     {
       // long process
     }

    }


    else
    {
     var expected =input as TypeB;
     foreach(var a in expected.Values)
     {
       //long process
     }
    }
```

> How can I declare `expected`  so that I don’t have to write the foreach statements twice? TypeA and TypeB are not related to each other in any way.

Comment: Are the "long process"s the same? Are the types of the two `a`s the same? Can you _make_ `TypeA` and `TypeB` related?

Comment: Everything inside the foreach is same. Those types are created via XSD and relating them in any way creates issues when deserializing.

Comment: Make an interface which exposes `Values`, and make both `TypeA` and `TypeB` implement that interface... then you can use a constraint on the method (`where T: IHasValues`). Otherwise, statically typed C# doesn't have duck-typing... the only way that'd work if `TypeA` and `TypeB` are not related would be using `dynamic` and letting the runtime find the `Values` property

Comment: " Those types are created via XSD and relating them in any way creates issues when deserializing." how do you serialize it? you can have a common parent class which will be serialized correctly if you write the appropriate attribute over the children classes.

Comment: [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237360/5174469) of how to solve serialization with inheritance

Comment: Following along from what @jcl said... I'm pretty sure (but not fully sure) that if create an interface that only has methods (no properties) like `IHasValues` and declare both of your types to implement that interface, it shouldn't get in the way of deserialization.  Of course, your foreach would call `expected.GetValues()` instead of looking at the Values property. By the way, read up on *pattern matching*. It can simplify a lot of code (though hopefully you don't need it here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given there's not a common type that `TypeA` and `TypeB` implement, you could do this:

```
public void Test<T>(T input)
{
    var expectedA = input as TypeA;
    if (expectedA != null)
    {
        Process(expectedA.Values);
    }

    var expectedB = input as TypeB;
    if (expectedB != null)
    {
        Process(expectedB.Values);
    }
}

private void Process(IEnumerable<Something> values)
{
    // long process
}
```

Or using pattern matching:

```
public void Test<T>(T input)
{
    if (input is TypeA expectedA)
    {
        Process(expectedA.Values);
    }

    if (input is TypeB expectedB)
    {
        Process(expectedB.Values);
    }
}
```

But it's better if we're not checking types. It implies that `input` could be pretty much anything, maybe not `TypeA` or `TypeB`. It's preferable for a method to only care about the *declared* type of an argument. So if you created an interface like this:

```
public interface IHasWhateverTheseValuesAre
{
    IEnumerable<Something> Values { get; set; }
}
```

`TypeA` and `TypeB` could both implement it. Then your method would look like this:

```
public void Test<T>(T input) where T : IHasWhateverTheseValuesAre
{
    foreach (var value in input.Values)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

The method doesn't care whether the input is `TypeA`, `TypeB`, or any other type, so it doesn't need to check. It will only compile if you're passing something that implements `IHasWhateverTheseValuesAre`, so the argument will always have that `Values` property.

---

You mentioned

> Those types are created via XSD and relating them in any way creates issues when deserializing.

That shouldn't matter. If you have an object of `TypeA` or `TypeB` that means it's already been deserialized. Having those two classes implement a common interface (which doesn't change them at all) wouldn't affect that.

---

Yet another way of looking at it:

If this method operates on a collection of values, should it even take `TypeA` or `TypeB` as an argument?

Perhaps it should just look like this:

```
public void Test(IEnumerable<Something> values)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use type 
**dynamic**.

```
public override void Test(object input)
{
 dynamic expected = input;
 if(input is TypeA)
 {
 foreach(var a in (expected as TypeA).Values)
 {
   // long process
 }

}

else
{
 foreach(var a in (expected as TypeB).Values)
 {
   //long process
 }
}
```

You can Make it more Generic.

```
switch (expected.GetType())
{
  case "TestA":
  //do something
  break;

  case "TestA":
  //do something
  break;

  default:
  throw new Exception("unexcepted Type!");
 }
```

If you are sure about types you can create an interface that implements List of Values then pass the Interface as an argument but it's not something generic, each time you should change the implementation of your class and you must sure that you have the same properties.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't recommend `dynamic`. If you were to use `dynamic` as shown here, you might as well remove the generic `T` argument and change the type to `object`. That would be the same as using `dynamic` in this case. The problem is that then you can pass any type to this method and it will compile. We should use the compiler to prevent incorrect code. Write the code so that it only compiles if we're passing the right thing to it. That way if it's wrong, we get a compiler error (quick, easy to find and fix) vs a runtime error (slower feedback, possibly harder to find.)

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks for Hint!just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to just write a method (assuming the two `a`s are not of the same type):

```
private static void MyForEachLoop<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
    foreach (var a in enumerable) {
        // long process
    }
}
```

Or, if the `a`s are of the same type, it doesn't need to generic:

```
private static void MyForEachLoop(IEnumerable<CommonTypeOfTheAs> enumerable) {
    foreach (var a in enumerable) {
        // long process
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
if(input is TypeA)
{
    var expected = input as TypeA;
    MyForEachLoop(expected.Values);
}
else
{
    var expected = input as TypeB;
    MyForEachLoop(expected.Values);
}
```